# Create Array dynamically PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I wanted to make an array dynamically using the given values of another array. Second, I want to convert the values of an array as input type.

Here's the example of given array

```
"data": [
        {
            "label": "Policy Number",
            "field": "account_number",
            "type": "Number",
            "is_required": true
        },
        {
            "label": "Amount",
            "field": "amount",
            "type": "Number",
            "is_required": true
        },
        {
            "label": "Due Date",
            "field": "due_date",
            "type": "Calendar",
            "is_required": true
        }
    ]
```

With that, I want to get the field values, so I created a for loop.

HEre's my code

```
$data = $response->data;

$fields = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
     $fields[] = $data[$i]->field;
}
```

I can get the field values. Now, I want to make an array generally, like

```
array(3) { ["account_number"]=> string(23) "value of account_number" ["amount"]=> string(15) "value of amount" ["due_date"]=> string(17) "value of due_date" }
```

Comment: where do you want to get the values for these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the value of field in the loop using `$fields[$data[$i]->field]` as a key for `$fields` and then add the value prepending the text `value of` and the value of field again.

```
$data = $response->data;
$fields = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $fields[$data[$i]->field] = "value of " . $data[$i]->field;
}
var_dump($fields);
```

Result

```
array(3) {
  ["account_number"]=>
  string(23) "value of account_number"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(15) "value of amount"
  ["due_date"]=>
  string(17) "value of due_date"
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/t2dUG)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function [array_push()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
<?php
    $cart = array();
    array_push($cart, 13);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But if you want to just assign value then you can do it like this way.

```
<?php
    $data =  '[
            {
                "label": "Policy Number",
                "field": "account_number",
                "type": "Number",
                "is_required": true
            },
            {
                "label": "Amount",
                "field": "amount",
                "type": "Number",
                "is_required": true
            },
            {
                "label": "Due Date",
                "field": "due_date",
                "type": "Calendar",
                "is_required": true
            }
        ]';
        $data  = json_decode($data);
        $fields = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
             $fields[$data[$i]->field] = "VALUE OF RESPECTIVE FIELD";
        }
        var_dump($fields);
    ?>
```